# SQL - Calculating YTD averages for each quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to calculate a YTD average for each quarter. For example:

- Q1 should show the average of Q1 data
- Q2 should show the average of Q1 and Q2 data
- Q3 should show the average of Q1, Q2 and Q3
- Q4 should show the average for all quarters.

It also needs to handle multiple years.  So if my data looks like this, I'm looking to add the Last column labeled YTD_AVG

```
   <---   I already have these  ---->   Need this field
Date      |    YEAR_QTR  |   VALUE  |   YTD_AVG
1/1/2019        2019Q1        10          11
1/6/2019        2019Q1        5           11 
2/20/2019       2019Q1        18          11
4/10/2019       2019Q2        7           10   <-- average of Q1 and Q2
6/10/2019       2019Q2        10          10
8/11/2019       2019Q3        25          15   <-- average of Q1, Q2 and Q3
9/1/2019        2019Q3        20          15
9/20/2019       2019Q3        25          15
```

etc..

Then when the year changes over to 2020 it needs to be able to know to start over at 2020Q1.

I was trying to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT a.*
       , YTD_QTR  = AVG(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY [YEAR],YEAR_QTR)
FROM(
    SELECT [DATE]
          , YEAR_QTR
          , datepart(year, COB_DATE) as [YEAR]
          , VALUE
    FROM #TABLE )  a
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: hi @DaleK - Updated with my query attempt that I coulnd't get to work for each ytd quarter.  I tagged the different versions because I assumed even an older method would still work on 2012, I don't have a huge amount of data so it doesn't need to be the latest and greatest and most optimal. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the CROSS APPLY operator (I think it's available in SQL Server 2012). See this answer:

But isn't your `YEAR_QTR` column wrong, 2019-10-20 = Quarter 4 right?

```
DECLARE @ValuesTable TABLE (
[Date] DATE,
YEAR_QTR VARCHAR(6),
[VALUE] INT
);
INSERT INTO @ValuesTable
(
    Date,
    YEAR_QTR,
    VALUE
)
SELECT '2019-01-01','2019Q1',10 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-01-06','2019Q1',5 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-02-20','2019Q1',18 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-04-10','2019Q2',7 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-06-10','2019Q2',10 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-08-11','2019Q3',25 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-09-01','2019Q3',20 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-10-20','2019Q3',25 

/*
Final output
*/
SELECT
  [Date],
  DATEPART(QUARTER,Date) [Quarter],
  VT.YEAR_QTR,
  [VALUE],
  YTD_AVG.YTD_AVG
FROM @ValuesTable VT
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT
    AVG(VT2.VALUE) YTD_AVG
  FROM @ValuesTable VT2
  WHERE 
    YEAR(VT.Date) = YEAR(VT2.Date) AND 
    DATEPART(QUARTER,VT2.Date) <= DATEPART(QUARTER,VT.Date)
)YTD_AVG
```

Comment: hi, yes that 10/20 date was incorrect for the quarter due to a typo, I updated the original post.  I will try this out and see how it works, thanks so much in advance!